# build regex with 2 expressions

Tags: regex

I need to build a regex and I don't know how to use "AND NOT"
Example: I've the following line

```
Default emulator : @{(default)="C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" %1}
```

My regex would be `The line contain "Default Emulator" AND NOT  ": @{(default)="C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" %1}"`

How can I build this?

Comment: `Default Emulator: (?!@\{\(default\)="C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore\.exe" %1\}\)` use a negative lookahead `(?!`...`)`

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: I write a script in python